# Join the first N characters of each word in a string with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

```
Name=pd.Series(['Ashton Smith', 'Diego Maradona ', 'Torres, Anna'])
frame ={'InputNames':Name}
result = pd.DataFrame(frame)
result1=result.InputNames.str.split(expand=True)
result['name0']=result1[0]
result['name1']=result1[1]
result
```

I am trying to select the first three letters in both first name and last name and then combine it.

However, there is a problem when I def my function.

```py
def my_fun(x, var1, var2, var3):
    print (x)
    if x[var1].astype(str).str[-1] ==',' :
        x[var3]=x[var1].astype(str).str[0:3]+x[var2].astype(str).str[0:3]
    else:
        x[var3]=x[var2].astype(str).str[0:3]+x[var1].astype(str).str[0:3]
    return x 

print (result.apply(lambda x: my_fun(x, 'name0', 'name1','ShortName'), axis=1))
```

```
<ipython-input-98-24dd0de94bd1> in my_fun(x, var1, var2, var3)
      1 def my_fun(x, var1, var2, var3):
      2     print (x)
----> 3     if x[var1].astype(str).str[-1] ==',' :
      4         x[var3]=x[var1].astype(str).str[0:3]+x[var2].astype(str).str[0:3]
      5     else:
```

> AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'astype'", 'occurred at index 0')

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share the output you want?

Comment: The names in your dataframe have different formating. E.g. the last row has the last name first. Do you care about such cases?

Comment: need last_name_three_chars+first_name_three_chars. the order is different when it has a comma. that's why I did if function

Comment: I used if statement to consider comma. Please see below, if that is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate through the dataframe simply. It might not optimal if you have big data frame.

```
new_column = []
n = 3 #number of characters you want to split and concanate
for i in result.loc[:, 'InputNames']:
    if ',' in i:
        concanated_string = i.split(', ')[0][:n] + i.split(', ')[1][:n]
    else:
        concanated_string = i.split()[1][:n] + i.split()[0][:n]
    new_column.append(concanated_string)

result['first_last'] = new_column
```

Comment: need  last_name_three_chars+first_name_three_chars.  the order is different when it has a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Split it up and then join it back. No need for `apply` here.

```
s = pd.Series(['Ashton Smith', 'Diego Maradona ', 'Torres, Anna'])

s1 = s.str.strip().str.split(r'[,\s]+')  
s1.str[0].str[:3] + '-' + s1.str[1].str[:3]

0    Ash-Smi
1    Die-Mar
2    Tor-Ann
dtype: object
```

Comment: need last_name_three_chars+first_name_three_chars. the order is different when it has a comma

Comment: @user12533116 If you understand the code, you would know you can just swap the order in which the chars are concatenated... right? I shouldn't have to explain that ;-) `s1.str[1].str[:3] + '-' + s1.str[0].str[:3]`

Comment: So helpful and I learned something new about Pandas today!

Answer (score 0):

Names are messy. E.g. your dataframe has one case where the last name comes first. Furthermore, what if you have names with only two letters like Ng? How do you deal with middle names?? Try avoiding looping through the values of your dataframe. Rather use `DataFrame().apply()`:

```
func = lambda x: ''.join([i[:3] for i in x.strip().split(' ')])
result.InputNames.apply(func)

0    AshSmi
1    DieMar
2    TorAnn
```